# How to use boost::graph to (approximately) solve the travelling salesman problem when entry and exit points to a node a different?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

Is it possible to easily solve the TSP using the [boost::metric_tsp_approx](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/graph/doc/metric_tsp_approx.html) function?

In it's current form [metric_tsp_approx](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/graph/doc/metric_tsp_approx.html) solves the following problem which is to find some approximately optimal path through a set of points, touching each point once.

[image]

the solution might be

[image]

However I have a more interesting variant I wish to solve

[image]

Above I have a series of segments in the plane. The segments need to be connected using a TSP solution but the connection is only allowed to enter on the green side and exit on the red side. For example a solution might be

[image]

where the yellow lines are solution. Is it possible to construct such a problem that boost::graph or metric_tsp_approx can solve it?

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible to easily solve TSP using any tool - it is considered to be NP-complete (if I remember correctly).

Comment: without looking at the details, your variation is just converting an undirected graph to a directed graph (where some of the edges go both ways, but the green edges are one way). Does that help? It's just the asymetric tsp variation.

Comment: @slava metric_tsp is an algorithm that solves the TSP to within 2 times the optimial. That is good enough for me. The question is whether it is possible to reuse this code whereby each vertex is a segment rather than a point.

Comment: @KennyOstrom No that is not quite right. The green lines would be mandatory in the solution. As well the documentation for metric_tsp says that it only works with undirected graphs. I might be out of luck :(

Comment: There has to be a node at the other end of the green line, or the question makes no sense. If there's not ... add one. TSP still has to visit them all, and all you need to do is implement TSP for a directed graph. As to whether this particular library already does that ... sorry. But it does look like a documented problem you can research. Maybe somebody else has it.

Comment: You can trivially transform your problem into an undirected TSP by turning each segment into a node, with an edge from segment node 1 to segment node 2 having cost `distance from exit of segment 1 to entry of segment 2` and so on. I can't tell at a glance whether the triangle inequality still holds, but `boost::metric_tsp_approx` requires an undirected graph and can't be used regardless. So no, you cannot use `boost::metric_tsp_approx` for that. And be careful with your wording, you're not really "solving" the TSP in either case, you're just hoping for a near-optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd treat the segments as nodes. No need to bother which side is entry/exit: you can decorate your path later.

So, make a graph model that has the segments as vertices, find an approximately shortest path `{ Segment1, Segment..., SegmentN }` using the current algo.

The path you are looking for can be expanded simply as:

```
{ entrypoint(Segment1), exitpoint(Segment1),
  ..., ...
  entrypoint(SegmentN), exitpoint(SegmentN) }
```

Comment: I would mention that this graph has to be undirected (because going from exit of segment 1 to entry of segment 2 will generally not cost the same as going from exit of segment 2 to entry of segment 1). That already answers the question whether `boost::metric_tsp_approx` can be applied (no, because it requires an undirected graph).

Comment: I think we don't really know enough. Maybe the the OP can transform the graph into am undirected graph-of-segments with appropriate weights (it seems that way to me, from his description).

Comment: The order of visiting the segments matters. If you have two segments A and B in 1D from 0.5 to 1.5 and from 1.5 to 2.5 then the segment-as-vertex graph has cost 0 from A to B and cost 2 from B to A. I don't see how you transform that into an undirected graph (while keeping the requirement of visiting each node once). I mean, I can't prove that there is no transformation with which this becomes tractable with `boost::metric_tsp_approx`, but the odds look bad.

Comment: @MaxLanghof You're probably right. I missed that part where the algorithm assumes that edge weights "obey the triangle inequality" - which indeed constrains the graph in ways I didn't include in my assumptions

Comment: (I had glossed over the "metric" part, basically I had assumed the image to be algorithmic graph renderings, without geometric relevance. If the geometric distances are leading, you're right and this approach doesn't work).